# *ngFor not working while inside a quote. *ngFor not working when using inside a Bootstrap Tooltip Tag

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

> .HTML File : It gives Error: Identifier 'mg' is not defined. However {{mgr[0].value}} works

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true"
title="<table class='popuptable'>
  <thead>
                        <tr >

                          <th>Current Value</th>
                                             
                        </tr>

                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor='let mg of mgr'>
                          <td>{{mg.value}}   

                        </tr>
                      </tbody>

                    </table>">
  Tooltip on bottom
</button>
```

> .ts file : I am trying to loop through this mgr using *ngFor in .HTML file

```
 mgr: any[]=[{
    value:'Work 1'
  },
  {
    value:'Work 2'
  }
  ];
```

Comment: Are you passing html as string in title attr, it will just resolve expression, directives like ngFor will not work,

Answer (score 2):

You can write the html code for the table inside  `<ng-template #tipContent></ng-template>` tags.

And then add the reference of the template to the **[title]="tipContent"** attribute of the button.

**Note**: Do not forget to put **[]** around the *title*.

You can refer to this article.  https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-ng-bootstrap-tooltip-tutorial/